# Xcode run button becomes analyze button

Tags: xcode, xcode8

I'm using Xcode 8.0. In that my run button becomes analyze button. How to change it back to run button?

**Screen shoot.**

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Long press on run button and select Build for running as below screenshot .
[image]